# How to bind json data to angularjs controller variable

Tags: angularjs, json

Json Data

```
   {
  "TotalRecordCount": 50,
  "Results": [
    {
      "TestId": 5002,
      "TestName": "Test 01/05/2016"
    }
  ]
}
```

My Service

```
 function getTestSchedule() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get(TestAppConfig.TestApiRoot + "/Tests/gettestschedule/").then(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }, function (resp) {
            deferred.reject(resp);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

My Controller Code

```
TestVm.test = TestModel.getTestSchedule;
```

So here controller is doing http call to web api, instead of http call how can I bind the page with the above json data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly but why don't you do:

```
TestModel.getTestSchedule().then(function(result) { TestVm.test = result; });
```

Maybe you'll have to replace `result` by `result.data`. Besides, your service is a bit weird, why don't you just do :

```
function getTestSchedule() {
    return $http.get(TestAppConfig.TestApiRoot + "/Tests/gettestschedule/");
};
```

Your code just creates a `Promise` mimicking the one returns by `$http.get` so you could simply return the one of `$http.get`.

**EDIT**

See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5IqDNDoN4ewb5klKnzeU

**EDIT 2**

Finally, according to the discussion below, the expected answer was simply:

```
TestVm.test = { 
    "TotalRecordCount": 50, 
    "Results": [ ... ] 
}
```

Comment: my question was how to dump json data into angular js scope variable `TestVm.test = json data`

Comment: Have a look at this: http://plnkr.co/edit/5IqDNDoN4ewb5klKnzeU the `data` variable contains the JSON contained in the `test.json` file, now you can do whatever you want with it ;-)

Comment: can I store json data in a variable and then use it in `TestVm.test = json variable` instead of using angular service and json file

Comment: Well... It depends on what exactly you want to do. You can store value at application level via the function `.constant` on your module, you can store hard coded data in a service (like the example above except that you can directly return the object instead of a promise), you can also store the hard coded value directly in your controller. Without more information, I can't tell you what you should do ;-)

Comment: well my requirement is simple i want to use json data into that controller scope variable to have a quick test on my side how page looks...I am not worried about creating constants or anything. Because after my test i am going to undo my changes

Comment: So why don't you just do `TestVm.test = { "TotalRecordCount": 50, "Results": [ ... ] }` ?

Comment: Alright then. Next time, please try to be a bit more specific in your questions ;-)